# Filtering out incomplete log entries

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell-script

I'm trying to get some garbage collection logs into Splunk.  However, when java starts garbage collection, it starts the log entry, then when it's done it puts in the end of the entry.  Splunk treats these as separate entries, so I'm trying to use cron to feed the logs into a separate file, and have Splunk monitor that file.

I've found that the incomplete log entries don't have a line feed character, so I've been trying to use grep, sed, or a perl one liner to filter those out.

I've tried these

```
cat <log file> | egrep "\n"
cat <log file> | sed '/\n/p'
perl -pe '/(?:\n|\r)+$/gm' <log file>
```

But, each time I get back the incomplete line (you can see my prompt at the end of the third line):

```
2013-10-11T13:21:43.952-0500: 56511.609: [GC 56511.609: [ParNew: 2457856K->271659K(2765056K), 0.5481470 secs] 5897437K->3711241K(11981056K), 0.5485080 secs] [Times: user=1.21 sys=0.00, real=0.55 secs]
2013-10-11T13:53:17.001-0500: 58404.658: [GC 58404.658: [ParNew: 2729515K->180830K(2765056K), 0.4755270 secs] 6169097K->3747097K(11981056K), 0.4758900 secs] [Times: user=1.29 sys=0.01, real=0.48 secs]
2013-10-11T14:02:56.084-0500: 58983.741: [Full GC (System) 58983.741: [CMS: 3566266K->3504629K(9216000K), 12.7932340 secs] 4444704K->3504629K(11981056K), [CMS Perm : 2082967K->2081438K(3393452K)], 12.7937180 secs][user@host ~]$
```

What method should I use to only match lines that end in a linefeed (\n) character?  Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with:

```
perl -ne 'print if /\n/' <log file>
```

example:

```
[root@ach tmp]# xxd ble
0000000: 610a 620a 630a 64                        a.b.c.d
[root@ach tmp]# perl -ne 'print if /\n/' ble
a
b
c
[root@ach tmp]#
```

Your perl code doesn't work because -p makes perl print every line (terminated by either \n or end of file character). You do some regex matching, but it doesn't affect anything.

```
perl -pe '/(?:\n|\r)+$/gm' <log file>
```